# How to change sub document after finding with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some code like below using mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/hoge');
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  children: [ChildSchema],
});
var ChildSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
}, {_id: false});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var Child = mongoose.model('Child', ChildSchema);

User.findOne({_id: '52299322fdbbdec515000001'}, function(err, user) {
  console.log(user);
  for (var i=0; i<user.children.length; i++) {
    var child = user.children[i];
    child.name = 'newchild';
  }
  user.save(function(err) {
    console.log(user);
    mongoose.disconnect();
  });
});
```

And here is my record in mongodb.

```
{
  "name" : "u1",
  "_id" : ObjectId("52299322fdbbdec515000001"),
  "children" : [ { "name" : "c2" } ],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

When I run the script, it outputs below.

```
{ name: 'u1',
  _id: 52299322fdbbdec515000001,
  __v: 0,
  children: [ { name: 'c2' } ] }

{ name: 'u1',
  _id: 52299322fdbbdec515000001,
  __v: 0,
  children: [ { name: 'newchild' } ] }
```

But my record in mongodb has not been changed. Why?

FYI, the record changed if I insert this code before saving.

```
user.children.push({name: 'somechild'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've resolved myself.

The problem is the order of declarating Schemas.

It worked if I tried this change.

```
/* first, children's schema */
var ChildSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
}, {_id: false});

/* seconds, parent's schema */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  children: [ChildSchema],
});
```