# Update field in sub document mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb, mongoose

My parent model

```
var GameChampSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  gameId: { type: String, unique: true },
  status: Number,
  countPlayers: {type: Number, default: 0},
  companies: [
    {
      name: String,
      login: String,
      pass: String,
      userId: ObjectId
    }
  ],
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updateAt: Date
})
```

I need insert userId property in first child where he is not set

So, need this action only on parent with condition ({status: 0, countPlayers: { $lt: 10 })

Comment: To clarify, Are there any elements in `companies` at all in what you are updating. If there are more do you want the **first** i.e 0 index, or *first matching*? If so *matching what*? And is it just that the `userId` field is not present or (different condition) `null`. Best to clarify that in an edit to your answer.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653652/how-to-change-sub-document-after-finding-with-mongoose?rq=1) solution. I hope it's help you.

Comment: I need insert userId to first company Object where userId is not set

Comment: @MaksimBorodov as I said that's not very clear. But do you mean just the first one that **matches**? I only ask because if there are multiple entries it would seem that the "login" or something would be a more logical match than just where the id was not set. Based on your schema. Is this true?

Comment: Can people seeing this **upvote** this question. It is a valid good question, and there is a valid approach. But the OP does not have enough reputation to get into a chat. And that would help with explaining. Still, I'll try and elaborate on the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an embedded document it is quite easy:

If you want to update a document that is the first element of the array, that **doesn't** have a userId

```
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "status": 0,
        "countPlayers": {"$lt": 10 },
        "companies.userId": {"$exists": false }
    },
    { "$set": {"companies.$.userId": userId } }
)
```

Which would be nice, but apparently this doesn't match how MongoDB processes the logic and it considers that nothing matches if there is **something** in the array that **does** have the field present. You **could** get that element using the aggregation framework but that doesn't help in finding the position, which we need.

A simplified proposal  is where there are no elements in the array at all:

```
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "status": 0,
        "countPlayers": {"$lt": 10 },
        "companies.0": {"$exists": false }
    },
    { "$push": {"userId": userId } }
)
```

And that just puts a new thing on the array.

The logical thing to me is that you actually **know** something about this entry and you just want to set the `userId` field. So I would **match** on the login:

```
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "status": 0,
        "countPlayers": {"$lt": 10 },
        "companies.login": login,
    },
    { "$set": {"companies.$.userId": userId } }
)
```

As a final thing if this is just updating the **first** element in the array then we don't need to match the position, as we already know where it is:

```
db.collection.update(
    { 
        status: 0, 
        countPlayers: {"$lt": 10 }
    },
    { $set: { "companies.0.userId": userId  } }
)
```

Tracing back to my **logical** case, see the document structure:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("530de54e1f41d9f0a260d4cd"),
    "status" : 0,
    "countPlayers" : 5,
    "companies" : [ 
        { "login" : "neil" },
        { "login" : "fred", "userId" : ObjectId("530de6221f41d9f0a260d4ce") },
        { "login": "bill" },
     ] 
}
```

So if what you are looking for is finding "the first document where there is no `userId`", then this doesn't make sense as there are several  items and you already have a **specific** userId to update. That means you must mean **one** of them. How do we tell which **one**? It seems by the use case that you are trying to match the information that is there to an `userId` based on information you have.

Logic says, look for the `key value` that you know, and update the *position* that matches.

Just substituting the `db.collection` part for your `model` object for use with Mongoose.

See the documentation on [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), as well as  [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) for the relevant details.

Comment: Ask please, how make this in mongoose syntax ?

Comment: @MaksimBorodov As I said. You use the name of the `var` you are using for your `Model` in place of `db.collection` in the statements. And add the callback details to make sure it doesn't fail. Otherwise there is no difference, it's just JSON notation.

Comment: @MaksimBorodov and for the record, which one of the three forms **was** what you needed?

Comment: I'm get error from mongo
"err": "Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.",
"code": 16650

I do it

var currentUser  = service.getCurrentUser(req);

  gameChamp.update(
    {
      "status": 0,
      "countPlayers": {"$lt": 10 },
      "companies.userId": {"$exists": false }
    },
    { "$set": {"companies.$.userId": currentUser._id } }, function(error) {
      res.send(error);
    }
  );

Comment: @MaksimBorodov Do you know **anything** about the item you are updating. ie the `login` value?

Comment: no, i need update first child where userId is not set and on first parent object where countPlayes < 10

Comment: @MaksimBorodov I'd like to get you into a chat but, since your rep is still to low. Is this as simple as the **absolute** first, as in **index** 0 element of the array? Because otherwise your reasons for matching just the **first one found** are eluding me. Which is why I keep asking if there is **something else** that defines **which** item you want.

Comment: @MaksimBorodov try seeing if the expanded content in the answer explains any of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks.

I solved his problem

```
exports.joinGame = function(req, res) {
  winston.info('start method');
  winston.info('header content type: %s', req.headers['content-type']);

  //достаем текущего пользователя
  var currentUser  = service.getCurrentUser(req);
  winston.info('current username %s', currentUser.username);
  //формируем запрос для поиска игры
  var gameQuery = {"status": 0, "close": false};
  gameChamp.findOne(gameQuery, {}, {sort: {"createdAt": 1 }}, function(error, game) {
    if (error) {
      winston.error('error %s', error);
      res.send(error);
    }
    //если игра нашлась
    if (game) {
      winston.info('Append current user to game: %s', game.name);
      //добавляем userId только к одной компании
      var updateFlag = false;
      for (var i=0; i<game.companies.length; i++) {
        if (!game.companies[i].userId && !updateFlag) {
          game.companies[i].userId = currentUser._id;
          updateFlag = true;
          winston.info('Credentials for current user %s', game.companies[i]);
          //если пользовател последний закрываем игру и отправляем в bw, что игра укомплектована
          if (i == (game.companies.length-1)) {
            game.close = true;
            winston.info('game %s closed', game.name);
          }
        }
      }
      //сохраняем игру в MongoDB
      game.save(function(error, game) {
        if (error) {
          winston.error('error %s', error);
          res.send(error);
        }
        if (game) {
          res.send({ game: game })
          winston.info('Append successful to game %s', game.name);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```